# Login log laravel 5

Tags: laravel, logging

I wanted to create user logs but something does not work for me.

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],
```

LogSuccessfulLogin.php

```
class LogSuccessfulLogin
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    { 
        Event::listen('auth.login', function ($user, $remember) { 
            $user->update([
                'last_login' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                'ip_address' => \Request::ip()
            ]); 
        });
    }
}
```

I read many tutorials but did not help

Answer (score 1):

You are telling Laravel to listing to the login event here:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],
```

Listening to the event within the handle statement is incorrect. The event has already been triggered.

If you remove the `Event::listen` from your handle method, it should work.

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  Login  $event
 * @return void
 */

public function handle()
{ 
    $this->user->update([
        'last_login' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'ip_address' => \Request::ip()
    ]); 
}
```

Comment: It still does not work, no errors show but the database does not register.

Comment: You might need to save the user as well. `$this->user->save();`. If that doesn't work do this `Log::info($this->user);` and post what your log shows.

Comment: I use methods update() 
So I do not have to perform the method save()

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: if i use save()

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-03-22 18:40:22, 2017-03-22 18:40:22))

Comment: That is a different issue. It is saying that you are creating a user record without one of the required fields, in this case the `name` field. If you look at your users table migration file, all the fields that don't specify as `->nullable()` are required. 

You have many options for resolving this issue. 

You can provide all the default values. 

Rollback you migration, change the name to nullable and re migrate. 

You can even just add a default value to your mysql directly, but that will come back to bite you.

Comment: I do not want to add a new record only update an existing one.

Comment: It's the same problem. When you update the user, it sees that the name field is not there and throws an error. You need to change your database so that the name field is nullable or has a default value.

Comment: fix problem $this->user = Auth::user();